# Javascript - json data not being transferred into memory properly

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file that contains 16,490 lines of data. Here's a snippet:

```
  [
     ...
     ["alrightty",2  ],
     ["alrighttyy",1  ],
     ["alrighty",100  ],
     ["alrightyy",1  ],
     ["alrigt",1  ],
     ...
  ]
```

This data will be used for my sentiment analysis thesis project. I used the following code to extract the data from the json file:

```
var positive_words_list = {}
function readJSONFile(filename,type) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: filename,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            switch (type) {
                case "pos" : positive_words = data; break;                    
                case "neg" : negative_words = data; break;                    
                case "afinn" : afinn_words = data; break;
            }
        },
        async: false
    });
}

readJSONFile('js/json/positivekeywords.json','pos');

for (var i = 0; i < positive_words.length; i++) {
    row = positive_words[i];
    positive_words_list[row[0]] = row[1];
};
```

What this code does is extract the data from the json file and then put it in a 1-dimensional array with each word as an array index and the number as the value.

Now I have this code run when the site loads inside $(function() { ... }); so positive_words_list should contain the data on load time. The thing is after the site loads and I do positive_words_list.length in the console, it outputs 63. As I said, there should be 16,490 entries.

Did I miss something? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

John

EDIT: I should add that when I do a positive_words.length in the console, I get the correct number of elements, 164,950

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an array.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the error. I converted it from a csv file using a website. I guess it's a JSON array? That's what it said. :S

Comment: Wait: `the thing is after the site loads and I do positive_words_list.length in the console, it outputs 63.` and then  `I should add that when I do a positive_words.length in the console, I get the correct number of elements, 164,950`. Please clarify.

Comment: See above code. In the function readJSONFile() it puts the data into positive_words. The for loop then has positive_words_list which is supposed to convert the data in positive_words into index=value for easier searching. See this image: http://i.imgur.com/qdxlZVc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see `positive_words_list` is a JavaScript object that does not have `length` property out of the box. So the only reason why you get the magic number 63 is because your array of arrays contain entity with word `length` as a first item; something like:

```
[
  ...
  ['length', 63],
  ...
]
```

In order to get number of keys in JavaScript Object you can either do `Object.keys(positive_words_list).length` or iterate over all properties and increment the counter:

```
function size(obj) {
  var key, 
      counter = 0;
  for(key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

size(positive_words_list); // <- will return number of properties in object
```

Your snippet may be modified in the following manner:

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="data">Number of positive words is ...</h1>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){

  var positive_words,
      positive_words_list = {};

  function readJSONFile(filename,type) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: filename,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              switch (type) {
                  case "pos" : positive_words = data; break;                    
                  case "neg" : negative_words = data; break;                    
                  case "afinn" : afinn_words = data; break;
              }
          },
          async: false
      });
  }

  readJSONFile('data.json','pos');

  for (var i = 0; i < positive_words.length; i++) {
      row = positive_words[i];
      positive_words_list[row[0]] = row[1];
  };

  $('#data').html('Number of positive words is ' + Object.keys(positive_words_list).length);

});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uhHZ1zEuUHXHIQrd1BVa?p=preview

Comment: I tried adding in the size() function you suggested, but it ended up outputting undefined. Not sure why it did that.

Comment: @kazuo Oh, it's my fault, I forgot `{` in the function definition. I updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: I just spotted that one a few minutes ago. Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

`positive_words_list` is an object, not an array, so you should result in:

```
positive_words_list["alrightty"] === 2
positive_words_list["alrighttyy"] === 1
```

and so forth. You can get an array of the keys of the object using:

```
Object.keys(positive_words_list)
Object.keys(positive_words_list).length
```

Which will return an array of the keys of your object. Note that `Object.keys` is an ES5 feature available in most current browsers.

Comment: Look again - it is an array. I believe the OP is trying to convert it into an object.

Comment: Looks like an object `positive_words_list = {};`